# Facebook login scope: public_profile object not returning picture, cover, age_range

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I provide a Facebook login button on my website.
I'm querying Facebook api v2.8 and try to access a user's `picture`, `age_range` and `cover` profile fields, which should be provided in the default `public_profile` object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

When connecting to my Facebook app I'm using this in my URL to determine scope: This works fine (but does not return picture,age_range,cover fields):

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=<MYCLIENTID>&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/login.aspx?loggedin=true&scope=email
```

But I'm getting only this returned:

```
{"id":"734565845333","email":"flo\u0040outlook.com","first_name":"Flo","gender":"male","last_name":"Unknown","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/734565845333\/","locale":"en_US","name":"Flo Unknown","timezone":5,"updated_time":"2017-04-30T10:46:29+0000","verified":true}
```

I checked here: [Satellizer Facebook login not returning the right scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502362/satellizer-facebook-login-not-returning-the-right-scope) and here [Facebook JS SDK's FB.api('/me') method doesn't return the fields i expect in Graph API v2.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584850/facebook-js-sdks-fb-api-me-method-doesnt-return-the-fields-i-expect-in-gra), where it's suggested to add the fields to the scope, but when I try:

`&scope=email,picture,age_range,cover,public_profile` or `&scope=email,picture,age_range,cover` Facebook returns a 500 error.

e.g.:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=<MYCLIENTID>&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/login.aspx?loggedin=true&scope=email,picture,age_range,cover
```

Why are the other fields not returned?

Comment: Show what API request you are making, and how you are asking for the fields.

Comment: I've added the full API calls, HTH!

Comment: That is the login dialog call. I meant the API call where you actually request the user’s information.

Comment: Ah thanks! That helped me find out that the scope parameters were not actually appended to the call to graph.facebook.com! Thanks!